# Consulta sql INNER JOIN com GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, inner-join

Tenho um select que está dando erro. A ideia é o resultado mostrar cinco colunas (CODPROD, DESCRPROD, CODLOCAL, DESCRLOCAL, ESTOQUE). Estou extraindo de quatro tabelas (TGFEST, TGFPRO, TGFLOC e TGFGRU) sendo que a coluna Estoque deve ser somada pois as tabelas trazem o mesmo produto várias vezes com estoque diferente em cada linha. Desse modo o objetivo é mostrar um produto por linha com a somatória do estoque desse produto. Neste caso estou filtrando por um tipo de local específico (EST.CODLOCAL).

**Segue o código:**

```
SELECT

PRO.DESCRPROD AS Produto,
SUM(ESTOQUE) AS Estoque,
EST.CODPROD,
EST.CODLOCAL,
LOC.DESCRLOCAL



FROM TGFEST EST 
    INNER JOIN TGFPRO PRO ON (EST.CODPROD=PRO.CODPROD)
    INNER JOIN TGFLOC LOC ON (EST.CODLOCAL=LOC.CODLOCAL)
    INNER JOIN TGFGRU GRU ON (PRO.CODGRUPOPROD=GRU.CODGRUPOPROD)

WHERE EST.CODLOCAL='1010000'

GROUP BY 

PRO.DESCRPROD,
EST.CODPROD

ORDER BY PRO.DESCRPROD
```

**Segue erro:**
ORA-00979: não é uma expressão GROUP BY

Grato se alguém puder ajudar,
Mário

Comment: No Oracle o group by tem de conter todas as colunas do select (fora as agregadoras).

Comment: @Motta grato pelo esclarecimento que foi fundamental para eu ter conseguido terminar minha atividade. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Vou deixar aqui o desfecho pois pode auxiliar a alguém que tenha a mesma dúvida que eu tive. Com a orientação do Motta, fiz o ajuste e alterei pequenos detalhes e o select ficou como eu precisava.

**Segue o select corrigido:**

```
SELECT

EST.CODPROD,
PRO.DESCRPROD,
EST.CODLOCAL,
LOC.DESCRLOCAL,
SUM(EST.ESTOQUE) AS ESTOQUE


FROM TGFEST EST 
    INNER JOIN TGFPRO PRO ON (EST.CODPROD=PRO.CODPROD)
    INNER JOIN TGFLOC LOC ON (EST.CODLOCAL=LOC.CODLOCAL)
    INNER JOIN TGFGRU GRU ON (PRO.CODGRUPOPROD=GRU.CODGRUPOPROD)

WHERE EST.CODLOCAL='1010000'

GROUP BY 
EST.CODPROD,
PRO.DESCRPROD,
EST.CODLOCAL,
LOC.DESCRLOCAL


ORDER BY DESCRPROD
```

Grato, Mário